# merge number by using "-" (python)

Tags: python, for-loop

this is python

```
temp_list=['1','2','3','5','7','8']
temp_list.sort()
print temp_list
test=""
first=""
last=""
start=0
for i in range(len(temp_list)):
    if i==0:
        None
    else:
        if (int(temp_list[i-1])+1)==int(temp_list[i]):
            print temp_list[i-1]
            print temp_list[i]
            if start==0:
                first=temp_list[i-1]
                last=temp_list[i]
                start=1;
            else:
                last=temp_list[i]
            if len(temp_list)==i+1:
                if start==0:
                    test+=(temp_list[i-1]+","+temp_list[i])
                else:
                    if len(test)!=0:#add
                        test+=(","+first+"-"+last)
                        start=0
                    else:
                        test+=(first+"-"+last)
                        start=0
        else:
            if start==0:
                test+=(temp_list[i-1]+","+temp_list[i])
            else:
                if len(test)!=0:#add
                    test+=(","+first+"-"+last)
                    start=0
                else:
                    test+=(first+"-"+last)
                    start=0
print test
```

this is sample code
this result -> 1-35,7,7-8

i want to convert number set followed:

ex1)
['1', '2', '3', '5', '7', '8']
->
1-3,5,7-8

ex2)
['0', '2', '3', '4', '5', '7', '8']
->
0,2-5,7-8

please help my brain

Comment: Not directly relevant, but you probably want `temp_list.sort(key=int)` (otherwise 10 will come between 1 and 2).

Comment: I think he wants to write a function that converts a list of numbers as strings into a list of strings that compresses consecutive numbers into ranges.

Comment: I tried all day but it is not rightly working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
def ints_to_ranges(l):
    if not l: return ""

    l = sorted(set(int(n) for n in l))
    ranges = [[l[0], l[0]]]

    for n in l[1:]:
       if n - 1 == ranges[-1][1]:
           ranges[-1][1] += 1
       else:
           ranges.append([n, n])

    return ",".join(r[0] == r[1] and str(r[0]) or "{}-{}".format(*r) for r in ranges)
```

It works by removing duplicate numbers, sorting them, building a list of ranges out of them, then formatting them. Example:

```
>>> ints_to_ranges(['1', '2', '3', '5', '7', '8'])
'1-3,5,7-8'
>>> ints_to_ranges(['0', '2', '3', '4', '5', '7', '8'])
'0,2-5,7-8'
```

Comment: I like the solution, but just a small suggestion:  `l` as a name is a little unclear.